# Show message box in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Add_Shipment_Method(
shipment_method_id_p IN NUMBER,
shipment_description_p IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO shipment_method 
    SELECT shipment_method_id_p, shipment_description_p
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SHIPMENT_METHOD WHERE SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID = shipment_method_id_p AND SHIPMENT_DESCRIPTION = shipment_description_p);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION WHEN
OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

The procedure generally allows adding a new shipment method into the table shipment_method when the row doesn't exist. 
I want to modify it and show a message box when the primary key 'shipment_method_id' does exist, and allows to write the row when it doesn't exist.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not show MessageBoxes from a Stored Proc.

Now for checking if the INSERT has inserted any row and show message in output window.

Use

```
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO shipment_method 
     SELECT shipment_method_id_p, shipment_description_p
     FROM dual
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SHIPMENT_METHOD 
                       WHERE SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID = shipment_method_id_p
                       AND SHIPMENT_DESCRIPTION = shipment_description_p);

     IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN           --if this is true, then no records were added.
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Not records added');     --writes this message

COMMIT;
```

Note: There should not be any other statement between the INSERT statement and "IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0" validation. SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects most recently executed statement.

Comment: Didn't understand that to be honest